# What exactly is the Structure-Dependency Principle

Tags: grammar, phrase-structure, dependency-grammar

Could someone explain what **structure-dependency** *is* in layman terms, and why it's so important?

Resources I've found on the internet weren't of much help so I'm asking on here.

Thanks!

Comment: What Google says is "The linguistic principle that grammatical processes function primarily on structures in sentences, not on single words or sequences of words." Those **are** laymen terms. All it says is that Constituents (phrases, clauses, idioms) are what's important, rather than "what part of speech is X?" or "is Y a gerund?" The first thing you do when you [figure out a sentence](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Howtofigureoutasentence.pdf) is to count the verbs so you can tell how many clauses there are. Then you can deal with each clause independently.

Comment: @Denisof, could you write a bit more about where (in what context) you read that term?

Comment: It was one of the questions addressed to Noam Chomsky during his interview to Alex Fridman on YouTube, can be found [here](https://youtu.be/MRcrJHxhWMY)

Comment: "The principle of structure-dependency compels all languages to move parts of the sentence around in accordance with its structure rather than just the sheer order of words", maybe this ThoughtCo article might be of help: https://www.thoughtco.com/structure-dependency-grammar-1691997